# Prevent ASP.NET Properties from Showing as Attributes in Custom Controls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

I have created a Custom ASP.NET Control which will act as a container with a specific wrapping tag:

```
class Section : System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
{
    public string WrapperTag // Simple interface to base-class TagName
    {
        get { return base.TagName; }
        set { base.TagName = value; }
    }


    public string BodyStyle
    {
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["BodyStyle"];
            return (o == null) ? "" : (string)o;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["BodyStyle"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        Attributes["style"] = BodyStyle + ";";
        base.Render(writer);
    }
}
```

This works without issue, except that the `BodyStyle` property also appears as an attribute in the HTML output for some reason. So, if I use the control:

```
<xx:Section runat="server" WrapperTag="div" BodyStyle="background-color:#ffeeaa;"><other stuff /></xx:Section>
```

This outputs:

```
<div BodyStyle="background-color:#ffeeaa;" style="background-color:#ffeeaa;"><other stuff HTML output /></div>
```

I'm trying to produce the output:

```
<div style="background-color:#ffeeaa;"><other stuff HTML output /></div>
```

My questions:

- Why does `BodyStyle` appear as an HTML attribute?
- Since `BodyStyle` appears, why doesn't `WrapperTag` appear as well?

Answer (score 1):

`BodyStyle` is written out because it exists in the `ViewState`. During `OnRender` the `HtmlGenericControl` adds all `ViewState` items as attributes. `WrapperTag` isn't in the `ViewState` so doesn't get written as an attribute. `_bag` is the StateBag.

Here's the render attributes implementation from reflector:

```
public void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if (this._bag.Count > 0)
    {
        IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = this._bag.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            StateItem stateItem = enumerator.Value as StateItem;
            if (stateItem != null)
            {
                string text = stateItem.Value as string;
                string text2 = enumerator.Key as string;
                if (text2 != null && text != null)
                {
                    writer.WriteAttribute(text2, text, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Change your code to this:

```
private string bodyStyle;

public string BodyStyle
{
    get
    {
        return bodyStyle ?? string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        bodyStyle = value;
    }
}
```